# How to import namespace when using third party lib with angular-cli

Tags: google-maps, angular, angular-cli, typescript-typings

According to Angluar-cli documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib), I succeed to import any third party library and then to use typings ([dt](http://definitelytyped.org/) and custom). Youhouou !

But for Google types, I have to prefix all my types by the `google.maps` namespace :

```
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

What can I do to use short names for types like this :

```
let geocoder = new Geocoder();
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Detail of my Google Maps import are here : [Getting started - How to use Google maps api with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816363/getting-started-how-to-use-google-maps-api-with-angular-cli/43366564#43366564)

==== EDIT ====

The @Nikky answer show me the mistake with the google namespace : It will be available at runtime only after the google maps script will be loaded.

So the problem is located in all the `constructor()` and `ngOnInit()` that use the google.map types :

```
  constructor() {
    this.load();                     //will begin goooglemaps script loading
    this.onReady().then(() => {      //subscribtion to script loaded event
      this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();//'google is not defined' at runtime
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the namespace and assign a name to it

```
import Geocoder = google.maps.Geocoder;
```

And then use it as if you were using native Geocoder API

```
let geocoder = new Geocoder();
```

Comment: I have an error at runtime : "google is not defined"

Comment: I make a call to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816363/getting-started-how-to-use-google-maps-api-with-angular-cli/43366564#43366564