# Embedding Google Map sometimes give error in Angular 4

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to embed Google Map into my angular 4 project. Most of the time it works but sometimes it gives following error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined .......`

Code snippet from my angular project:

**index.html:**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Angular Project</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_MAP_KEY"
  async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

(I have removed my Google map access key from above pasted code)

**map.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
      zoom: 8
    });

  }
}
```

**map.component.html:**

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

Most of the time above code works but sometimes it doesn't. I think this might be because sometimes `this.initMap()` execute before  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_MAP_KEY" async defer></script>` is fully loaded. To avoid this I have used `ngAfterViewInit()` but then also it is not working.

Please suggest right method to do this.

**Error screenshot:**
[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never personally enjoyed implementing Google Maps into Angular projects, so I've been primarily using [this package](https://angular-maps.com/). And totally recommend you trying it. It should simplify your map initialization with it's custom map components. So all you'd need to do is...

`<sebm-google-map [latitude]="-34.397" [longitude]="150.644"></sebm-google-map>`

Comment: Its nice. But I want to do it myself, not by using third party package.

Comment: Let's try this then... `npm install --save @types/google-maps` and then in your `tsconfig.app.json` add... `"types": ["googlemaps"]`. Is that does the trick I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Maybe this will help... (It's a bit of work for set up) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43366564/5076023