# asp.net core 2.0 spa angular + google map

Tags: asp.net, angular, google-maps, .net-core

How can i implement google map in asp.net core spa angular application, i have include script in to my index.cshtml but got error while accessing it from angular.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
}
```

> Index.html

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR-KEY]" async defer></script>
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google
>   is not defined ReferenceError: google is not defined at new
>   HomeComponent (F:\yo\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16281:25)

Comment: Error ? what was it.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined
ReferenceError: google is not defined
at new HomeComponent (F:\yo\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16281:25)

Comment: You are loading `<app> </app>` which is related to `AppComponent` so need to get `declare var google: any` google in `AppComponent` and store it local storage and use it where ever you want.

Comment: can you help me with example?

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816363/getting-started-how-to-use-google-maps-api-with-angular-cli) could help

Comment: @RohitShrestha the script `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR-KEY]" async defer></script>` which you  are added is not related to `declare var google: any;` just I reproduce the issue get to know the correct reason.

Comment: so how can i add google map to the project

Comment: Added example, hope it helps!

Comment: how can i access google map then..

Answer (score 0):

.cshtml

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"
         asp-prerender-data='@ViewData["token"]' >Loading...</app>//Storing 

    <script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @section scripts {
        <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    }
```

boot.server.ts

```
setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString(),

                        globals: {
                            tokenData: params.data
                        }

                    });
```

app.component.ts

```
declare var tokenData: any;
@Component({..})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 ngOnInit() {
 let accessToken = tokenData;
 localStorage.setItem('token', accessToken);
     }
}
```